# Vue.js: prevent user clicking on element while it is being transitioned with Vue <transition>

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on a Vue.js project, and when I click on an element, I'm using the Vue transition tag to fade it out. The problem is that as the element is in the process of being faded out, it is still clickable, which in my application can cause issues.

My question is: how can I make an element unclickable during a transition, so that users don't click it multiple times before the transition finishes?

I've already tried applying a css class with point-events: none; to the element right when the transition starts, but it didn't stop clicks during transition.

Example:

```
<transition name="fade">
  <div v-if="shouldShow" @click="doSomeAction">Example text</div>
</transition>
```

(where doSomeAction sets shouldShow to false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue has event modifiers that might help with that. The specific one which might be helpful to you is @click.once. If you add this to the click event the user will only be able to click it once. Documentation for it is [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vue.js 2.6+ you can do it with ease. In this minor realse **Dynamic directive arguments** was added, so you can conditionally bind desired event name, or in you case disable it (passing `null`).

> Dynamic argument values are expected to be strings. However, it would
>   be convenient if we allow `null` as a special value that explicitly
>   indicates that the binding should be removed. Any other non-string
>   values are likely mistakes and will trigger a warning.

[Reference](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0003-dynamic-directive-arguments.md?source=post_page---------------------------).

```
// using computed property
<transition name="fade">
  <div v-if="shouldShow" @[event]="doSomeAction">Example text</div>
</transition>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
       shouldShow: true
     }
  },
  computed: {
    event() {
      return this.shouldShow ? "click" : null;
    }
  }
}

// using object
<transition name="fade">
  <div v-if="shouldShow" v-on="{ [shouldShow ? 'click' : null]: doSomeAction }">Example text</div>
</transition>
```

Comment: This is a great answer! It's a little bit more verbose than "click.once" answer given, but it's still helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

If you also need to ensure that users can immediately click "through" the element that is being faded out to items behind it, you can add a class with **pointer-events: none;** to the element, and then do this:

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
  this.shouldShow = false;
});
```

This will make sure the fade doesn't happen until the class has been added. this.$nextTick is a Vue function that waits for the dom to update (which in this case is adding the pointer-events class) before running a callback: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick

Note that pointer-events: none; doesn't work on some very old browsers (IE < 10)